# ElasticSearch: How to specify specific fields to search at?

Tags: elasticsearch

Right now in my mapping, I am setting "include_in_all" to true, which means all the fields are included in _all field.

However, when I am searching, instead of wasting space, and putting everything in the _all field, I want to specify the specific fields to certain for (and taking into account the boost scores in the mapping).

How do I create a query that tells Elastic Search to only look at specific fields(not just 1) and take into account the boosting I gave it during my mapping?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Start with a [multi_match](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/query-dsl/multi-match-query/) query. It allows you to query multiple fields, giving them different weights, and it's usually the way to go when you have a search box.

```
{
  "multi_match" : {
    "query" : "this is a test",
    "fields" : [ "subject^2", "message" ]
  }
}
```

The query_string is more powerful but more dangerous too since it's parsed and can break. Use it only if you need it.

Comment: does this override the boosting I gave to those fields during my initial mapping?

Comment: It's additional, but then you wouldn't need index time boosting anymore.

Comment: thanks javanna, another question: any idea how to combine a filter AND multi match query like the one in your answer?

Comment: Just looking at that new question you posted ;)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to keep data in `_all` field to query for a field.

You can use [query_string](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/query-dsl/query-string-query/) or [bool](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/query-dsl/bool-query/) queries to search over multiple fields.